# Python - loop through subdirectories with textual content on them and copy just a part on a text file

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I am quite new on Python but I am obliged to use it this time!
This is my problem:

I have a **directory** called **"Test"**. 
In this directory there are many **subdirectories**, called: "1", "2", "3", "4", **"5"**, and so on. 
In every **subdirectory** there are a lot of **text files**.

What would I like to have as a result?

I should be able to iterate through subdirectories and to divide the content in 2 separate files: **test.txt** and **train.txt**. This action must be made for *every* subdirectory.

For example:

case 1 ---
the related text file in subdirectory 1, will be the test.txt file  --- 
the related text files in 2-3-4-5-etc subdirectories will be the train.txt

case 2  ---
the related text file in subdirectory 2 will be the test.txt  ---
the related text files in subdirectories 1-3-4-5-etc will be the train.txt

case 3  ---
the related text file in subdirectory 3 will be the test.txt  ---  the related text files in subdirectories 1-2-4-5-etc will be the train.txt
and so on...

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You want a *directory* to be `test.txt`?  What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @zondo As I wrote in the directories there are many text files. I don't want the directory to be test.txt but the content of the directory itself (the files in the directory)

Comment: You want to create 2 files with the contents of many files appended to them?

Comment: @dawg yes ! So in case 1, I will use the content of the subdirectory 1 for test.file and the content of subdirectories 2,3,4,5,etc. for train.txt ... Then I will continue using the content of subdirectory 2 for test.file, and 1,3,4,5,etc. for train.txt ... and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#

Semi - Solution found

for i in range (1,4):
    print (i)
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        nb_dir = rootdir+str(i)
        if nb_dir == subdir:
            for file in files:
                f = open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')
                fcontent = f.readlines()
                ftest.write(str(fcontent)+"\n")

        else:
            for file in files:
                f = open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')
                fcontent = f.readlines()
                ftrain.write(str(fcontent))

test.txt
['Hello']
['World']
['!!!']

train.txt
['!!!']['World']['Hello']['!!!']['Hello']['World']
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is **only one** file in the subdirectory, you can try like this (should renames all the files to train.txt first):

```
import glob,os
while True:
    # Your test case number
    trainnum=raw_input("Input test case number:\n")
    ftrain=open('train.txt','w')
    ftest=open('test.txt','w')
    for subdir in glob.iglob('*/'):
        # The subdirectory for test case
        if subdir.rstrip('/') == trainum):
           for fr in glob.iglob(subdir+os.sep+"*.*"):
                 with open(fr) as f:
                      ftest.write(f.read())
       else:
           for fr in glob.iglob(subdir+os.sep+"*.*"):
                 with open(fr) as f:
                      ftrain.write(f.read())
   ftest.close()
   ftrain.close()
```

If there are many files in subdirectory, I don't know which file you want to rename...

Update: just an example. You should further check it.

Comment: The problem is that in every subdirectory there are many text files (more than 400 ! ). I should be able to put the content of all these text files of that subdirectory to a file called "train.txt"

Comment: You just want to generate a **test.txt** and **train.txt** file in the *Test* directory?

Comment: yes with the content of the related subdirectory in the right order everytime